# ETL Derived column issue

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2019, etl

I'm following this tutorial for learning ETL and SSIS tools. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/9067/transformations-in-sql-server-integration-services-ssis/

The tutorial seems fine, however, when I tried on the VS 2019 package the new columns (test and date) are not added to the result.

[image]

I can see that the data is recovered properly from MSSQL source(only the 4 columns extracted from the DB, at that stage the extra columns should be present).

[image]

And there are no issues associated.

I was testing adding some static information. Initially, the first column appeared, then when I added the second column the information is not rendered anymore.

[image]

I added some management to review if there are errors in the derived column but, everything seems to be fine.

Also, I checked the progress explorer and errors are presented during the data flow operations.

[image]

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please be specific - what is the column names that you are talking about when you say "the new columns are not added to the result."? The warnings are just telling you aren't using certain columns. In SSIS you often need to just open and close downstream components to make them see changes you've made upstream

Comment: Hi Nick, the new derived columns are test and date.